# regex for getting particular output from sentences in python

Tags: python, regex

I have some sentences:

```
[1, 23] fun(): Error Code: 1230. fun doen't exist

Error Code: 1123. Unknown column 'hhh'

END: Error Code: 2134. database doen't exist
```

Now my concern is i want to get output like

```
['Error Code: 1230. fun doesn't exist','Error Code: 1123. Unknown column 'hhh'','Error Code: 2134. database doen't exist ']
```

I use `\sError\s` this regex  , but it didn't work , i do code in python

How to make a regex for it?

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'\bError Code.*', s)`

Comment: bro it works , put this into a ans section , i want to mark it as "accepted" @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Done, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'\bError Code.*', s)
```

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `Error Code` - a literal substring
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qGmnT6/1).